# Проблема с WHERE-условием в ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Коллеги, добрый день! Пытаюсь выбрать строки где `x.c_node > 1` и делаю так:

```
 select x.g guid, x.c_node chg_nodes
  from
    (select dta.g g, xmlquery('count(//Charge)' passing dta.pack returning content) as c_node
      from
      (select md.guid g,
        case
          when md.message is not null or md.message like '<%'
          then extract(xmltype(md.message), '/')
          else null
        end as pack
          from rnip.md_table md
        where md.creation_date between to_date('01.06.2014 00.00.00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('28.02.2015 23.59.59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and md.message_type = 'Charge'
      ) dta
    ) x
 where x.c_node > 1;
```

В итоге выхлоп такой:

> ORA-22950: невозможно сортировать объекты без методов MAP или ORDER
>   22950. 00000 -  "cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method"
>   *Cause:    an object type must have a MAP or ORDER method defined for
>              all comparisons other than equality and inequality comparisons.
>   *Action:   Define a MAP or ORDER method for the object type Error at Line: 15 Column: 9

Я не понимаю, что надо ордерить... Заордерил все что можно и как можно, результат не меняется. Как выбрать `x.c_node > 1`?

Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно проблема в XML где то? Если убрать последнее условие, вывод работает? Похоже, что содержимое x.c_node нельзя сравнивать на больше\меньше. Что символизирует это условие?

Comment: Если условие убрать выгрузка работает. Не думаю что проблема в XML, так как в `x.c_node` записывается результат `xmlquery('count(//Charge)' passing dta.pack returning content)`, там просто целочисленные значения...

Comment: А какой результат хочется получить таким запросом? я правильно понял, что в результате в c_node просто числа, и интересует те строки, где эти числа больше 1 ?. Похоже что полученный объект `xmlquery('count(//Charge)' passing dta.pack returning content) `просто не может быть отсортирован. Попробуйте привести его как нибудь к числу или строке.

Comment: Все верно, нужно получить числа больше 1. Если привести к числу, то выхлоп без изменений, а если к строке то: ORA-00932: несовместимые типы данных: ожидается NUMBER, получено -

Comment: Не понял, про приведение к числу и строке. Можно примеры кода? И пару примеров содержания строки

Comment: Мой предыдущий комментарий есть следствие моей криворукости, я пытался привести к числу `x.c_node`, а надо было приводить `xmlquery('count(//Charge)' passing dta.pack returning content)`. Теперь все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что нельзя отсортировать не числовое значение возвращаемое в `x.c_node`. Для решения необходимо привести к типу `xmlquery('count(//Charge)' passing dta.pack returning content)` Решение подсказал **lDrakonl** за что ему огромное спасибо!

```
 select x.g guid, x.c_node chg_nodes
  from
    (select dta.g g, to_number(xmlquery('count(//Charge)' passing dta.pack returning content)) as c_node
      from
      (select md.guid g,
        case
          when md.message is not null or md.message like '<%'
          then extract(xmltype(md.message), '/')
          else null
        end as pack
          from rnip.md_table md
        where md.creation_date between to_date('01.06.2014 00.00.00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('28.02.2015 23.59.59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and md.message_type = 'Charge'
      ) dta
    ) x
 where x.c_node > 1;
```